# Windows 10 shell not repainting

Tags: windows-10

I have two fresh installs of windows 10 2004 that seem like the windows shell isn't repainting. This is causing several problems such as the start menu having a small program list and any windows settings page I go to does not scroll.

[image: Small Start Menu List]

I've tried to reset/reinstall windows, re-register the shell experience host, reinstall all appx packages, and using the local admin account.
EDIT: I've checked and applied all driver and windows updates.

I think the 2004 update of windows changed some things with the start menu. Any suggestions on what I should try?

Answer (score 0):

I have two fresh installs of windows 10 2004 that seem like the windows shell isn't repainting.

That is not a general issue with Windows V2004 or beyond (new Insider versions).

Use the manufacturer's Driver Update app and update all drivers including BIOS and also particularly the Video Driver.

Then update Windows again after the above updates and check your issue.

Also make sure there is no legacy software installed (just in case). V2004 is working very well otherwise.

Also run the Windows 10 compatibility assistant to ensure your computer is compatible with newer Windows 10.

Finally, contact Vendor (Lenovo) Support as they may have a fix we have not seen yet.

Comment: @WillBixler - You should edit your question and mention that fact.  Temporary commentary will be removed.

Comment: Make sure there is no legacy software at all.  Also, if all drivers are up to date, is there a compatibility issue with your machines and Windows 10 going forward?

Comment: No software is installed at all yet, let alone legacy. I'm confused about what you're asking in the second part of your question. Are you asking if the machine supports windows 10? If so then yes it does. It's a Lenovo ThinkStation P330 Tiny.

Comment: There are lots of Windows 10 Drivers for that machine and all my machines are Lenovo.   Have you contacted Lenovo Support for a fix?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll reach out to them.